# Synonymize [web-applications] with [website-design]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Can we please synonymize [web-applications](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) with [website-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design)? There's only 23 questions with the tag and all that I've seen are applicable websites in generaly, not limited to web applications. As such, the website design tag is more applicable.

Comment: yes please *filler*

Comment: not anymore! now there's only 4 closed questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the two serve different functions though [web-applications](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-applications) doesn't appear to be getting used properly very often.

Things like Pixlr would be a web-application. Webflow would be another web-application.

Questions about their usage though could be tagged with just Pixlr or Webflow and whatever other tag(s) is appropriate... print design, typography, page-layout, etc.

I don't see any reason to keep web-applications at all.

Would destroying the tag be more appropriate?

Comment: Trogdor! Trogdor! :D

Comment: I'm fine with this, provided someone wants to retag the questions that should have website-design on them

Comment: @ZachSaucier not it!

Comment: *[Inconspicuously places finger on nose]*

Comment: destroooy!!!!!!

Comment: I retagged all of the questions, the only ones left are the closed questions. Should I retag those as well?

Comment: @luciano Thanks! Yes, we should retag all questions

Comment: all retagged. ready to destroy!

Comment: @Luciano thanks, the tag will be gone in 24 hours. It requires a CM to blacklist the tag though so this will not prevent users from recreating it.